# Асинхронность в реалиях 3.5

Tags: c#, .net

Вопрос. Как реализовать асинхронность, не прибегая к сторонним библиотекам. В `4.5` мы имеем `await` и `async`, в 4.0 мы имеем `Task` `Task<T>`. В `3.5` мы имеем только `BeginInvoke`

Интересует принцип описания асинхронного метода, который в свою очередь будет вызывать внутри себя ряд методов, в этом же потоке, или в другом, и ждать завершения работы их, с возможностью получения результата метода, или без (`void` метод). Пример в 4.5 примерно это выглядит так:

```
void async DoIt()
{
...
var a = await AsyncDoItSomething();
...
}
```

Comment: Откуда такое ограничение - "не прибегая к сторонним библиотекам"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov не хочется везти за собой вагон и маленькую тележку сторонних библиотек, тем более стандартными средствами можно реализовать, а это интересней.

Comment: _В 3.5 мы имеем только BeginInvoke_ - ну так почему бы и не использовать?

Comment: @Grundy интересует принцип описания, тот же самый await с результатом,а не только лишь стрелять потоком в неизвестном направлении.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос, что ты понимаешь под _принцип описания, тот же самый await с результатом,а не только лишь стрелять потоком в неизвестном направлении._ Сейчас не совсем понятно что именно ты хочешь получить. В принципе никто не мешает посмотреть исходники `Task` и взять то. что надо тебе например.

Comment: async/await - это ключевые слова. Поэтому стандартными средствами 3.5 ты никак ни сможешь записать `void async DoIt(){await AsyncDoItSomething();` - будет ошибка синтаксиса. Но ты можешь реализовать класс аналог Task с методом `ContinueWith`

Comment: @Grundy в вопросе я оговорился уже об том что async await существует в .net 4.5

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51246/discussion-between-grundy-and-paranoidpanda).

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskParallelLibrary/ - официальная (tm) реализация Task<T> для 3.5

Comment: Плюс [https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35/) для поддержки ключевых слов async и await.